# AngularJS click to edit fields such as dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I stumbled upon this [article](http://icelab.com.au/articles/levelling-up-with-angularjs-building-a-reusable-click-to-edit-directive/) on how to build a click to edit feature for a form.  The author states:

> What about if you wanted input type="date" or even a select? This
>   is where you could add some extra attribute names to the directive’s
>   scope, like fieldType, and then change some elements in the template
>   based on that value. Or for full customisation, you could even turn
>   off replace: true and add a compile function that wraps the necessary
>   click to edit markup around any existing content in the page.

While looking through the code I cannot seem to wrap my head around how I could manipulate the template in such a way that I could make it apply to any angular component, let alone how I can make it apply to a drop down list.  Code from article below:

```
    app.directive("clickToEdit", function() {
    var editorTemplate = '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
        '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '{{value}} ' +
            '<a ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '<input ng-model="view.editableValue">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="save()">Save</a>' +
            ' or ' +
            '<a ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        template: editorTemplate,
        scope: {
            value: "=clickToEdit",
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.view = {
                editableValue: $scope.value,
                editorEnabled: false
            };

            $scope.enableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
                $scope.view.editableValue = $scope.value;
            };

            $scope.disableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
            };

            $scope.save = function() {
                $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue;
                $scope.disableEditor();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

My question is, how can we extend the above code to allow for drop down edits?  That is being able to change to the values that get selected.

Comment: Could you provide the remaining code for the directive?

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo code added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach you might consider is using `template: function(tElement,tAttrs )`.

This would allow you to return appropriate template based on attributes.

```
app.directive("clickToEdit", function() {
      return {
       /* pseudo example*/
        template: function(tElement,tAttrs ){
             switch( tAttrs.type){
                 case 'text':
                    return '<input type="text"/>';
                 break;
             }
        },....
```

This is outlined in the [$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile)

Comment: interesting, is `radio` the case statement I would want to consider for a drop down list?

Comment: up to you what convention you use... personally I would use `select` since that's what the tag is

Comment: sure I was looking at the doc and was basing it on the left hand menu  where it is input [xxx]

Comment: you could also store templates in `$templateCache` and use `templateUrl: function` to pick the one you want. Directives are very powerful and can be customized in many many ways

Comment: good to know.  So for the purposes of my example, I would leave everything the same, but add the `template:` and figure out any additional styling?  I ask because I presume it isn't just:  
`case select :  return <input type="select"/>';`

Comment: You can run any code you want in the function, just return the html wanted. I used `switch` just for example and "select" is not a valid type for `<input>`

Comment: sure sure.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  However, since the above example already works for `text` inputs, this doesn't actually answer the question, but good information regardless.

Comment: answer what question?

Comment: the question in my original post, about what the implementation for a drop down would be

Comment: Oh.. set attribute to `select` , and output a `<select>` tag. I assumed that part was fairly easy to figure out from example. Pass data collection into scope and use `ng-options`

Comment: right right.  Just wanted it for completeness sake, especially if you get the bounty.